# Angular nested ng-repeat - reuse first one after second

Tags: angularjs

I have the following example nested ng-repeats:

```
<div ng-repeat="item1 in controller.items1>
    [[ item1 ]] // This displays properly
    <div ng-repeat="item2 in controller.items2">
        [[ item2 ]] // This displays properly
    </div>
    [[ item1 ]] // This doesn't get displayed
</div>
```

It would seem that the nested ng-repeat is stopping the first one from being used later in the code. Can someone please help with how the first ng-repeat can be used in there?

Comment: Can you creat a jsfiddle/plunker for that ?

Comment: The way you have it written, the same [item1] should display twice.  Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: there definitely isn't any reason why this wouldn't work; are you sure that you are looking at the output correctly? http://plnkr.co/edit/EvxFEoGFJr1fMDCMLnWF?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine. Check below example -

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="app">
  <div ng-repeat="item1 in items1">
    {{item1.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="item2 in items2">
      {{item2.name}}
    </div>
    {{item1.name}}
  </div>
</body>

var app = angular.module('app', [])

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.items1 = [{
      name: 'Item1 - One'
    }, {
      name: 'Item1 - Two'
    }, {
      name: 'Item1 -Three'
    }, {
      name: 'Item1 - Four'
    }];

     $scope.items2 = [{
      name: 'Item2 - One'
    }, {
      name: 'Item2 - Two'
    }, {
      name: 'Item2 - Three'
    }, {
      name: 'Item2 - Four'
    }];
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing an inverted comma in your first ng-repeat. Which should give you a Syntax Error:

```
<div ng-repeat="item1 in controller.items1">
    {{ item1 }} 
    <div ng-repeat="item2 in controller.items2">
        {{ item2 }}
    </div>
    {{ item1 }}
</div>
```

Also if you have a one dimnesional array structure like this:

```
var self = this;
self.items1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'];
self.items2 = ['i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'];
```

It should work just fine :).

Answer (score 1):

check with  the below code and its worked fine for me.try with angular brackets to print the out put and also check the below code

HTML

```
<div ng-app='myapp'>

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="s in palletElement ">
    {{s.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="s1 in test" >
    {{s1.Data}}
    </div>
    {{s.Data[0].lenght}}
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

controller.js

```
(function(){
    angular.module('myapp', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        var counter = 0;

        $scope.palletElement = [{
            name: 'Pallet 1',
            Data: [{
                name: 'item 1',
                itemId: '284307',
                shipmentId: 'eb44f690-c97a-40e3-be2a-0449559e171a',
                itemCode: '',
                description: 'Bicycle parts - frame',
                quantity: '31',
                handlingUnit: 'CTN',
                weight: '613.04',
                class: '',
                lenght: '102',
                width: '42',
                height: '61',
                flag: 'P'

            }, {
                name: 'item 2',
                itemId: '284308',
                shipmentId: 'eb44f690-c97a-40e3-be2a-0449559e171a',
                itemCode: '',
                description: 'Bicycle parts - fork',
                quantity: '22',
                handlingUnit: 'CTN',
                weight: '242.99',
                class: '',
                lenght: '75',
                width: '34',
                height: '18',
                flag: 'P'
            }]
        }]; 
        $scope.test = [{
            name: 'Pallet 1',
            Data: [{

                quantity: '31',
                handlingUnit: 'CTN'

            }, {

                quantity: '22',
                handlingUnit: 'CTN'

            }]
        }];
    });
}());
```

output i got:

```
Pallet 1
[{"quantity":"31","handlingUnit":"CTN"},   {"quantity":"22","handlingUnit":"CTN"}]
102
```